# React app showing form in dialog results in a "findDOMNode is deprecated" error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

I have a react app, the parent component has a button which when clicked shows a simple dialog with one text input and a submit button. Strict mode is enabled. There are two issues

1. The form input is set to show an initial value (formik `initialValues` is set) in the input but that is not being set
2. When the button is clicked I see an error in the console;

`Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference.`

The dialog component comes from Material UI and the form comes from Formik. I've created a simple repro [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ybbh1?file=/ProfileEditor.tsx). The error is in the dev tools console. What would cause that error and why is the value not initialising?

Here's the parent component;

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

import ProfileEditor from "./ProfileEditor";

function ProfileManager() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Typography variant="h5">Profile Manager</Typography>

      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleOpen}>
        Open profile editor dialog
      </Button>

      <ProfileEditor open={open} onClose={handleClose}></ProfileEditor>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProfileManager;
```

and the dialog component displayed when the button is clicked in the component above;

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Dialog,
  DialogContent,
  LinearProgress,
  TextField
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { Formik, Form } from "formik";

interface Props {
  open: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
}

function ProfileEditor(props: Props) {
  return (
    <Dialog open={props.open}>
      <DialogContent>
        <Formik
// initial value not being displayed !!! 
          initialValues={{
            firstName: "Billy"
          }}
          onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              setSubmitting(false);
              alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            }, 500);
          }}
        >
          {({ submitForm, isSubmitting }) => (
            <Form>
              <TextField name="firstName" type="text" label="First name" />
              {isSubmitting && <LinearProgress />}
              <br />
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                disabled={isSubmitting}
                onClick={submitForm}
              >
                Submit
              </Button>
              <Button variant="contained" onClick={props.onClose}>
                Close
              </Button>
            </Form>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

export default ProfileEditor;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a value prop to the form field to have it initialized properly.

```
{({ submitForm, isSubmitting, values }) => (
<Form>
    <TextField
    name="firstName"
    type="text"
    label="First name"
    value={values.firstName} /* you need this prop */
    />

    ...
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-react-formik-inside-material-dialog-sfq4e?file=/ProfileEditor.tsx

---

Regarding your issue on the console, I'm not entirely sure at this point what is causing it, but if it bothers you or is causing additional problems, perhaps you can opt to move out of strict mode

```
<React.Fragment>
  <ProfileManager></ProfileManager>
</React.Fragment>
```